# SQL Check Constraint with User Defined Function

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, constraints, integrity

I am troubleshooting an issue seen in our sql server database recently.

Table 1 has a calculated bit column based off of a user defined function which checks if a record exists in another table and evaluates to 0 if not.

Table 2 is the table searched by the function for Table 1.  Table 2 also has a check constraint using a function to see if the bit field in Table 1 is set to 1.

This seems like a circular dependency.  The problem is that when inserting a batch of records into Table 2, the constraint fails.  Inserting these same records 1 by 1 allows all of the inserts to go through.  I can't for the life of me figure out why batch inserts cause it to fail.  Any help is appreciated.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tPecosPriceCheckStoreSubcategory](
    [PecosPriceCheckID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [StoreID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SubcategoryID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [UndirectedExpectedScans] [int] NULL,
    [PriceMin] [decimal](8, 2) NULL,
    [PriceMax] [decimal](8, 2) NULL,
    [PastPriceVariancePercent] [decimal](5, 2) NULL,
    [ChangeDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [IsUndirected] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [IsDirected]  AS ([dbo].[fnPecosPriceCheckStoreSubcategoryIsDirected]([PecosPriceCheckID],[SubcategoryID])),
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tPecosPriceCheckStoreSubcategory] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [PecosPriceCheckID] ASC,
    [StoreID] ASC,
    [SubcategoryID] ASC
)
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tPecosPriceCheckStoreSubcategory] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_IsUndirected]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [IsUndirected]
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnPecosPriceCheckStoreSubcategoryIsDirected]
(
   @PecosPriceCheckID int,   
   @SubcategoryID int
)
RETURNS bit
AS
BEGIN

   declare @isDirected bit
   set @isDirected = 0
   if (exists (select 1 from tPecosDirectedPriceCheckItem  where PecosPriceCheckID = @PecosPriceCheckID and SubcategoryID = @SubcategoryID ))
   begin
        set @isDirected = 1
   end
   return @isDirected  

END



CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tPecosDirectedPriceCheckItem](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [PecosPriceCheckID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PecosItemID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ItemSortOrder] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SubcategoryID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ChangeDate] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tPecosDirectedPriceCheckItem] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tPecosDirectedPriceCheckItem]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [CK_tPecosDirectedPriceCheckItem_CheckPriceCheckSubcategoryDirected] CHECK  (([dbo].[fnCheckDirectedItemPriceCheckSubcategory]([PecosPriceCheckID],[SubcategoryID])=(0)))
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tPecosDirectedPriceCheckItem] CHECK CONSTRAINT [CK_tPecosDirectedPriceCheckItem_CheckPriceCheckSubcategoryDirected]
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnCheckDirectedItemPriceCheckSubcategory]
(
   @PriceCheckID INT,
   @SubcategoryID INT
)
RETURNS BIT
AS
BEGIN

   DECLARE @isViolation BIT

   SET @isViolation = 
   CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tPecosPriceCheckStoreSubcategory WHERE SubcategoryID = @SubcategoryID AND PecosPriceCheckID = @PriceCheckID AND IsDirected = 1)
   THEN
      0
   ELSE
      1
   END   

   RETURN @isViolation

END
```

Comment: Showing the code used to implement this would help.

Comment: The `check` constraint seems totally redundant.  The behavior you describe is totally possible, depending on the data in the tables and the data being inserted.  Without more details, it is hard to be more precise.  I could describe a particular situation where this would occur, but you already have one.

Comment: My first guess is that your batch insert contains a record that violates the check constraint.   What is the error that results when it "fails"?